# xss issue-- Injection of data from a file ("buffer") to servlet response.  CASE OF FILE DOWNLOAD INJECTION

Tags: file, xss, code-injection

```
    FileOutputStream fos;
    HSSFWorkbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook();
    wb=aaaaa.getExportXLS(request, response, fileName, wb);
    fos=new FileOutputStream(uploadDir+File.separator+fileName);
    wb.write(fos);
    File fileXls=new File(uploadDir+File.separator+fileName);
    fileInuptStream = new FileInputStream(fileXls);
     bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInuptStream);
                      byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                    byte [] buffer = new byte [length];
                    while ((offset = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, start, length)) != -1)
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, start, offset);


                    buffer = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
                    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
                    response.setContentType("application/xls");
                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName );
                    response.setContentLength((int ) fileXls.length());
                    response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
```

I have this piece of code. at the line having the syntax response.getOutputStream().write(buffer); a issue is been reported that it is vulnerable to xss attack. the report is from a code audit tool from the client side. the message delivered say " Injection of data from a file ("buffer") to servlet response (possible XSS attack)". I dont know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

After working for few more hours I understood the issue reported is of file download injection. And the solution lies in the ESAPI using the method

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader().
```

But I want more information and usage details about this method as at two places and in a research paper I came to know about the method

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().safeSetHeader("Content-Disposition",
"attachment; filename=" + fn );
```

and the implementation of this above method is not present rather they are suggesting the setHeader method.
Do anyone have any prior experience with this type of issue and the solution implemented. Please share your experience/ solution/ suggestions.

Comment: no body have a suggestions..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to have a lot of validation. 
The issue is with the request as input in the method retrieving data from the database. It can initiate the attack. validate the filename and others output  before writing it in the response.

Comment: Can you provide your sample code so it can be useful to others also.